# Multiple useRef() in a map loop with three fiber not working

Tags: reactjs, three.js, use-ref

I have a parent component which loops through myIcons and loads some Models. I want to access those Models in useEffect, but the useRef().current.length is 0;

```
const itemsRef = useRef([]);
useEffect(() => {
        console.log(itemsRef.current.length); // is 0 why?
        for (let i = 0; i < itemsRef.current.length; i++) {
            //do something with all the refs.. e.g. place Models on a circle
        }
    }, []);


const myIcons = ["zoom", "bell", "message"];

return (
        <>
            {myIcons.map((icon, i) => {
                return (
                    <Model
                        key={i}
                        what={icon}
                        castShadow
                        receiveShadow
                        ref={el => (itemsRef.current[i] = el)}
                    />
                );
            })}
        </>
    );
};
```

Model:

```
const Model= ({ what, position }) => {
    const ref = useRef();
    const { scene } = useGLTF(
        process.env.PUBLIC_URL + `models/fbx-file/${what}_out/${what}.gltf`
    );
    return <primitive  ref={ref} object={scene} />;
};
```

I saw some examples where this is working, but in this case the array of refs is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and the first error i got was

> Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

So i wrapped your Model component with forwardRef (note, it accepts a function that takes (prop, ref) so you see ({...}, ref) in that way)

Just works and shows 3 in console.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, forwardRef } from "react";

const Model = forwardRef(({ what, position }, ref) => {
  return <div ref={ref}></div>;
});

export default function App() {
  const itemsRef = useRef([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(itemsRef.current.length); // is 0 why?
    for (let i = 0; i < itemsRef.current.length; i++) {
      //do something with all the refs.. e.g. place Models on a circle
    }
  }, []);

  const myIcons = ["zoom", "bell", "message"];

  return (
    <>
      {myIcons.map((icon, i) => {
        return (
          <Model
            key={i}
            what={icon}
            castShadow
            receiveShadow
            ref={(el) => (itemsRef.current[i] = el)}
          />
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit adoring-minsky-pzkvn7]

Note: if you are worried about why console.log prints 2 times - thats because of `<StrictMode>` in index.js.